# How are databases used to implement document collaboration?

Tags: database, sharepoint, google-docs, collaboration, consistency

How are document collaboration tools such as Google Docs and Sharepoint implemented in the backend? What kind of database architecture in the backend is used to implement features such as multiple people editting the document simultaneously. How is this done efficiently efficiently for large documents without having each edit update an entire database entry?

And how do they maintain the complete version history of every single edit while not using up tons of disk space?

Do Google Docs and Sharepoint have degrading performance for very very large documents?

Comment: This is not a good question for [so]. Please read the [faq].

Comment: I read the faq. I don't see the problem with this question.